# stored data in local storage and retrieve it and display using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to store user input in Local Storage, then retrieve it and display using JavaScript. I'm getting errors saying:

> Cannot read property `'innerHTML'` of `null`

and

> `key` is not defined

```
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Insert Data</legend>
            <input type="text" id="inputKey" placeholder="enter key">
            <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="enter value">
            <button type="submit" id="insertBtn">Insert Data</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
       <legend>local Storage</legend>
       <h3 id="lsOutput"></h3>
    </fieldset>

<script>

let inputKey = document.getElementById('inputKey');
let inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue');
let inputButton = document.getElementById('insertBtn');
let output = document.getElementById('IsOutput');
inputButton.addEventListener("click", store);
function store(){
     const key = inputKey.value;
     const value = inputValue.value;

  if( key && value){

      localStorage.setItem(key, value);

    //   location.reload();   
  }
}
  for(const i = 0 ; i < localStorage.length; i++){
      const getKey = localStorage.key(i);
      const getValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
      output.innerHTML += `${getKey}: ${getValue}`;
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code has multiple errors and mistakes. Please try to debug it, and include your attempts here. To do that, read https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging and https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve

Comment: thank you. ill go through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few errors:
`IsOutput` instead of `lsOutput`
You have to test `undefined` value in javascript (`key` and `value`)
On the loop `i` can't be a constant (because you increment it...)

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>    
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Insert Data</legend>
        <input type="text" id="inputKey" placeholder="enter key">
        <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="enter value">
        <button type="submit" id="insertBtn">Insert Data</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>local Storage</legend>
        <h3 id="lsOutput"></h3>
    </fieldset>

    <script>
        let inputKey = document.getElementById('inputKey');
        let inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue');
        let inputButton = document.getElementById('insertBtn');
        let output = document.getElementById('lsOutput');
        inputButton.addEventListener("click", store);
        function store() {
            const key = inputKey.value;
            const value = inputValue.value;

            if (key != "undefined" && value != "undefined" ) {

                localStorage.setItem(key, value);

                for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                    const getKey = localStorage.key(i);
                    const getValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
                    output.innerHTML += `${getKey}: ${getValue}`;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the **key** to the variable **getKey**:

```
const getKey = localStorage.key(i);
const getValue = localStorage.getItem(getKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getKey = localStorage.key(i);
```

I think you can't do that because key is not a method of the localStorage object,

Only getItem, setItem, removeItem and clear can be used

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use getItem(key)

```
  for(let i = 0 ; i < localStorage.length; i++){
      const getKey = localStorage.getItem(key[i]);
      const getValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
      output.innerHTML += `${getKey}: ${getValue}`;
  }
```

Notice that I also changed a bit on your loop. You should use let, not const here, as the variable will increment at each loop. also, you want to use bracket notation when getting the particular item within a loop, not parantheses.

also, once you have your key, you also have your value.

Consider this:

```
localStorage.setItem('some key', 'some value');
const item = localStorage.getItem('some key');
console.log(item);
// -> 'some value'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your HTML, in your JavaScript, you are looking for id `IsOutput` but are naming your element with `lsOutput`. Remember that querying for non existent elements returns null.

ALso, try using `getItem` instead of `key`

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

This is because you element is not available. There is type error **LsOutput** instead of **IsOutput**

Also Check this line, seems wrong?

```
  for(const i = 0 ; i < localStorage.length; i++){
      const getKey = localStorage.key(i);
      const getValue = localStorage.getItem(key); 
     //above line seems wrong instead of key it should be getKey 
      output.innerHTML += `${getKey}: ${getValue}`;
  }
```

---

Issue is your type error **LsOutput** instead of **IsOutput** i.e IS not LS

Comment: `Storage.prototype.key` actually exists; just tried it in my browser console